# SkinID in CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, skinning

is there any way to change skinId in codeBehind? 
I tried it during setting other property, but it's not working. The skin is not applied.

```
public GlobalImageButtonType Skin {
            get { return _skin; }
            set 
            {
                _skin = value;
                this.SkinID = _skin.ToString();
                this.CommandName = _skin.ToString();

                LoadDefaultValues();
            }
        }
```

I also tried loop throught page.contols, but in page_onpreinit event is controls collection empty.

Is it possible to change the SkinId elsewhere than in aspx page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SkinID** can only be changed programmatically on or before **OnPreInit** - your only option to initiate this for a control is in the Page's **OnPreInit**.

Under normal circumstances, **.Controls** should be available at that stage.

In some cases, you need the following work-around for **.master** pages:

```
            /*
             * HACK: need to ensure master controls are instantiated first.
             * */
            MasterPage root = this.Master;
            while (root.Master != null)
                root = root.Master;

            InvokeControlPreInit(Controls);
```

You can now have controls that need skinning implement some interface (IRuntimeSkinableControl) that allows them to assign their own skins:

```
    private void InvokeControlPreInit(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            IRuntimeSkinableControl skinableControl;

            if (null != (skinableControl = control as IRuntimeSkinableControl))
                skinableControl.OnPreInit();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.SkinID) && control.Controls.Count > 0)
                InvokeControlPreInit(control.Controls);
        }
    }
```

The control would apply it like so:

```
public class UserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IRuntimeSkinableControl
{
    public virtual void OnPreInit()
    {
        //assign this.SkinID
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the tip. Although, it would be a little better if you actually included the implementation of the custom interface. It took me some time to figure it out, but in the end it worked out great.